# Is it possible to log in to google services via Oauth 2 on the server-side without browser?

Tags: java, scala, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I'd like to use the google universal analytics API on the server side. The idea is that there is a browser app showing some graphs which is open to the intranet and doesn't require a login at all. So server either does the login for client and provides the working token to the client or the server provides all the data to the client as well. Oauth login docs and libs from google rely on redirect urls etc which sounds painful for a server-side login . So is it possible and are there any tutorials?

Comment: i think better to query and authentication on the server and then provide the data to the client